Java asynchronous servlets
We are using asynchronous servlets with the following mechanism (Asynchronous servlet not acting asynchronously)
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/test" }, asyncSupported = true)
public class TestServ extends HttpServlet  implements AsyncServletTaskProcessor{

    /** The exec. */
    private ExecutorService exec;

    public int CALLBACK_TIMEOUT;

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // read callback timeout form web.xml as init parameter
        CALLBACK_TIMEOUT = Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("timeout"));
        // read thread pool size form web.xml as init parameter
        int size = Integer.parseInt(getInitParameter("threadpoolsize"));

        exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);

    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {

        rs.setContentType("text/plain");
        rs.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        //AsyncContext asy = rq.startAsync(rq, rs);
        //asy.start(new Client(asy));

        final AsyncContext asy = rq.startAsync();

        // set the timeout
        asy.setTimeout(CALLBACK_TIMEOUT);

        // attach listener to respond to lifecycle events of this AsyncContext
        asy.addListener(new AsyncListenerImpl(asy));

        // spawn some task in a background thread
        exec.execute(new AsyncServletTaskRunner(asy, this));
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

    @Override
    public void process(AsyncContext ctx) throws IOException, ServletException {
       //do whatever you want to do as process of each thread
    }
}

class AsyncServletTaskRunner implements Runnable {
...
}

The readers and writers are written using ReadListener and WriteListener  with ServletOutputStream.
The thread pool size is 5.
Question: We have 5 different asynchronous servlets. Each of them has its own Executor. Each has different mapping, /test1, /test2 etc. But if the number of users increaeses and the time for processes takes more than 10 seconds, we start getting IllegalStateExceptions and the pages becomes unressponsive.
Should we use a common Executor for all servlets? What about the pool size? Should we use only one asynch servlet for the application and differentiate in implementation?
Another question is we see examples of asynch servlets without using any Executor, instead of Executor the usage is as following, which approach is better?
using Executor:
exec.execute(new AsyncServletTaskRunner(..));

or
asy.start(new AsyncServletTaskRunner(..); 


Why? Just use Web Sockets or SSE provided by standard Jakarta EE API. This tech  based on async servlets is already crystallized and standardized. No need to reinvent the wheel and potentially blow up the server by attempting to manually manage the threads instead of letting the server manage them.

I don't follow why the answer to the question you link recommends the servlet creating its own executor, or why, if it's going to recommend doing that, it does not recommend a ManagedExecutorService that uses container-managed threads and provides container context.  It seems overly complex, too, not least in that it puts the task processing code into the servlet itself (which you seem to have copied) for no good reason.  (It's not safe to access that object asyncronously, as it may be taken out of service at any time.)  Overall, I would not model my code on any of that.

@BalusC thank you. But the project is huge and already in production. Switching to websockets or jakarta demands extra time and resources, which we do not have currently. Our requirements are not such big, max. 1000 concurrent users, each process may take up to 5-10 minutes. We use tomcat 9.x (recent). Without asynch, we had thread starvation, using asynch resolved most of issues.

Thank you @JohnBollinger. As you suggested removing the executor and simply by calling asy.start(new Runnable()) works without problems currently.

"Switching to websockets or jakarta demands extra time and resources, which we do not have currently" continuing this path and monkeypatching afterwards will ultimately cost more time and resources especially when members of development team change (and thus new devs need to be reeducated non-standard/homegrown approaches).


Question: We have 5 different asynchronous servlets. Each of them has its own Executor. Each has different mapping, /test1, /test2 etc. But if the number of users increaeses and the time for processes takes more than 10 seconds, we start getting IllegalStateExceptions and the pages becomes unressponsive.

That doesn't sound surprising.  You're using FixedThreadPoolExecutors to run relatively long-running tasks, so you can relatively easily overcome the concurrent processing ability you set up.
But the problem starts earlier.  Java EE applications are not at liberty to create their own threads at will, however they want.  If you insist on using an executor service, then you must use a container-managed one.  But I don't immediately see why you should need to do so.  Java EE containers already manage multiple threads, and AsyncContext has a built-in mechanism for hooking into that.

Should we use a common Executor for all servlets? What about the pool size? Should we use only one asynch servlet for the application and differentiate in implementation?

You probably should not set up your own executor service at all, but if you do (see above) then I don't see what is to be gained by having a separate one for each servlet.
And I see no particular advantage to trying to load all async behavior on a single servlet.

Another question is we see examples of asynch servlets without using any Executor [...]

Yes.  AsyncContext.start() assigns the specified task to a container-managed thread.

which approach is better?

I guess that depends on the application, but I recommend AsyncContext.start() until and unless you discover that it is somehow insufficient (and how, and why).  If you ever reach that point then you will have all the information you need to decide the needed properties of your own ManagedExecutorService.

Some Servlet containers such as Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Jetty do not offer Jakarta Concurrency features. Which explains why some folks, and possibly the OP here, are managing threading and executor services manually.

@John Bollinger using AsyncContext.start() seems working better thank for detailed answer i mark it as accepted
